# show loading screen when service worker is fetching new version

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I am using a service worker to cache/update our application but we want to "force" that the user always has the most recent version of the application. 
The reason for this is we don't want to get calls from previous versions.

We are blocking our API calls already when we find that the user is using an old version of the application.

But now we want to hook into the Angular Service Worker to show the loading screen when he is fetching a new version. 
Until now I haven't found a way to do this. 
I am trying it with the following code:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/ngsw-worker.js').then(registred => {
    console.log('-- registred worker', registred);

    registred.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
      console.log('-- fetching', event);
    });

    registred.addEventListener('install', event => {
      console.log('-- installing', event);
    });
    registred.addEventListener('updatefound', event => {
      console.log('-- found a update?', event);
    });
  });
}
```

I cannot seem to listen to the fetch events (Which I assume is the event I want)

Or is there another way to just see if there is a new version ? 
Or is there maybe a better library/way to use service worker so I get a little bit more control?

Hope somebody can help me out!

Comment: I've never seen attaching a fetch event listener done in this way. Usually the fetch event listener is registered from within the service worker JS file itself, rather than from outside. Does this work?  AFAIK a registration (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration) is not a service worker (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker) and so the code would not work, as a fetch event is not a valid event for a registration to listen for.

Comment: No this code does indeed not work (it was my effort to try it). But is there a way that I can listen/know that the service worker is fetching something in the background?

Comment: Use `skipWaiting()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/skipWaiting). See the example for how to use in the `install` event. This would be inside your `ngsw-worker.js` file.